# Using custom decoder inside ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I have a custom decoder developed using HEVC HM software. I want to use this decoder in place of the ffmpeg decoder when using ffmplay. Is it possible to directly integrate my decoder as an executable file (a linux executable) inside the ffmpeg code? 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to integrate an executable file inside ffmpeg code. What are your reasons for such approach?